# What is Gradle build system in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I was reading the Kotlin documentation and I came across the statement,
*By default, your project will use the Gradle build system with Kotlin DSL.*
What does it mean?
I've seen Gradle Kotlin option while making a new project in IntelliJ:
[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ project configuration]

Can somebody explain me these, and which Bundle I should be using as a beginner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **build system** combines and simplifies some of the key tasks involved in building and distributing your program. The main things a build system does include:

- Downloading any **dependencies** your application has
- Running **tests** against your application
- **Compiling** your code
- **Packaging** up your application and its dependencies into a form you can share with others

You could run all of these tasks separately yourself, but build systems make it a lot easier and less prone to mistakes. In practice, all but the smallest projects use some kind of build system. Gradle is one such tool, but you can also use Maven, or the tools built into an IDE like IntelliJ.

### Which one should I use?

If this is a personal project, the build system and tools built into an IDE like IntelliJ are more than good enough.

If you're working with other people, you might want to consider a standalone build system instead. That's because standalone build systems like Gradle can be used with multiple IDEs, and can also be used on the command line without an IDE at all. Large projects with many contributors will often run a build server that runs the build system in an automated way against all new changes, to make sure the code builds and runs as expected.

IDEs like IntelliJ have very good integration with the common build systems, including Maven and Gradle, so you won't disadvantage yourself by choosing them over the built-in IDE tools.

### Maven, Gradle, or Gradle with Kotlin?

There are plenty of other resources you can find comparing Maven with Gradle. The crucial difference, though, is the way you write the **build script** that allows you to customise the dependencies, tests, and other parameters of your build.

- In **Maven**, your build script is an **XML** file. It follows a rigid structure, providing inputs and configuration to existing tasks and plugins.
- In **Gradle**, the build script was historically written in **Groovy**, a loosely-typed language that gives you a lot of flexibility. As well as configuring tasks and plugins, you can easily add your own tasks and functions.
- You can also choose to write Gradle build scripts in **Kotlin**. This offers the same flexibility and customisation as Groovy, but the addition of a type system means the IDE can give you much more help with writing the script correctly.